# Change textbox behavior when it's too full

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Currently when I type too much into a textbox it does goes from this:

```
[This is the text I'm    ]
```

To this:

```
[is the text I'm entering]
```

With the beginning of the text hanging off the left. I'd rather it continued showing the start of the sentence instead, like this.

```
[This is the text I'm ent]
```

But allowing the user to continue typing into it, with what they're typing being not visible, without the above described scrolling behavior. Is this already a property of textboxes?

**Alternative question:** Is there a way to *detect or fix* the text box if it's in a condition like this:

```
[m entering              ]
```

when the entire textbox contains "This is the text I'm entering". In other words, when it's showing white space in favor of contents it has. This can be caused by copying and pasting into the box.

Comment: WinForms, WPF, or Store?

Comment: WinForms, added tag.

Comment: So when the user mistypes a letter he/she is not  able to see the error? IE if one types `enternig` the typo will be invisible? Not really a good idea.

Comment: This is the desired behavior, yes. In practice the text box will be expanding to fit the text (which *should* solve the problem, but the scrolling gets out of whack occasionally, just disabling it would be much easier than dealing with each situation where it happens). Also it makes sense in situations where the text is displayed fully elsewhere as the user types so errors can be checked as they type.

Comment: Don't know if that's possible since the caret always wants to be in focus.  Maybe just put the TextBox inside a Panel and give the Textbox a maximum width, but you really are putting your users at a disservice.

Comment: What's a disservice to my users is when they paste 50 characters of text into a 5 character text box, it resizes to the correct size but only displays the last 5 characters and 45 spaces of nothing, because of overzealous scrolling. I need a way to disable this effect so I can manually control it.  I'd rather not add any more controls, it already takes a few seconds to load.

Comment: Are the users typing or copying/pasting into the textbox?  Your last comment is different than the question you posted.

Comment: Pasting, typing, and using dictation software which I assume is comparable to pasting text in word by word. It doesn't matter how the text is entered, disabling the described effect is my goal, because without it the textbox behaves flawlessly. Rather than coming up for a little patch for the known copying and pasting problem, only to discover some other way this scrollbar-less scrolling screws me over later, I'd like to just disable it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of any setting to modify this behavior.

There are alternatives:

1. Create your own textbox.  That's a lot of work, but will give you complete control over every aspect of text entry.
2. Create a shadow/proxy textbox.  It's hacky, but...

   - Place a textbox off screen.
   - When the visible textbox gains focus, switch focus to the shadow.
   - In the TextChanged event, copy the contents to the visible textbox, and set its cursor position to zero (to always keep the front of the text visible).

Comment: I added a very related question, maybe you can help with that?